# Function run on multiple elements inserts multiple images

Tags: javascript

I have a function that is called on multiple li elements when you scroll to the bottom of the page. The function removes a class and creates an image element based on the data- attribute of each li:

```
function createImg(param) {
    var img = $('<img>');
    img.attr('src', $(this).attr("data-src"));
    img.appendTo(this);
}

$(window).scroll(function () {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() === $(document).height()) {
    $("li.hidden").slice(0, 2).removeClass('hidden').each(createImg);
});

<ul>
                <li class="hidden" data-src="img/1.jpg">
                    <p>1</p>
                </li>

                <li class="hidden" data-src="img/2.jpg">
                    <p>2</p>
                </li>

                <li class="hidden" data-src="img/3.jpg">
                    <div class="image-cont"></div>
                    <p>3</p>
                </li>
</ul>
```

However now I want to create the image within div.image-cont within the li. Ive tried the javascript below but it creates multiple images within each div.image-cont rather than just 1 in each:

```
function createImg(param) {
        var img = $('<img>');
        img.attr('src', $(this).attr("data-src"));
        img.appendTo(".image-cont", this);
    }

<ul>

                    <li class="hidden" data-src="img/1.jpg">
                       <div class="image-cont"></div>
                        <p>1</p>
                    </li>

                    <li class="hidden" data-src="img/2.jpg">
                       <div class="image-cont"></div>
                        <p>2</p>
                    </li>

                    <li class="hidden" data-src="img/3.jpg">
                        <div class="image-cont"></div>
                        <p>3</p>
                    </li>
    </ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function createImg(param) {
    var img = $('<img>');
    img.attr('src', $(this).attr("data-src"));
    //img.appendTo(".image-cont", this);
    $(".image-cont", this).append(img);
}
```

Using append rather than appendTo solved this.

Comment: Please always include explanations to code in answer, so that future readers better understand its purpose.